# How iteratively reduce the number of rows in a group according to a given condition PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table like:

| start_dt | end_dt | ID | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-03-08 | A | i |
| 2023-05-08 | 2023-06-18 | A | i+1 |
| 2023-12-09 | 2024-02-02 | A | i+2 |
| 2024-12-01 | 2025-01-05 | A | i+3 |
| 2023-02-01 | 2023-03-07 | B | j |
| 2023-06-08 | 2023-07-18 | B | j+1 |
| 2024-12-09 | 2024-02-02 | B | j+2 |

I need to create new one which satisfies the conditions (for each ID separately):
if start_dt[i+1] - end_dt[i] < 9 months, then the rows i and i+1 collapse, start_dt_new = start_dt[i], end_dt_new = end_dt[i+1].

so the resulted table will look like

| start_dt | end_dt | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2024-02-02 | A |
| 2024-12-01 | 2025-01-05 | A |
| 2023-02-01 | 2023-07-18 | B |
| 2024-12-09 | 2024-02-02 | B |

how can I do it with PostgreSQL?

What I tried:

```
create table test (
    
    start_dt date,
    end_dt date,
    id varchar(10)
    
);


insert into test(start_dt, end_dt, id)
    values (date'2023-01-01', date'2023-03-08', 'A'),
    (date'2023-05-08', date'2023-06-18', 'A'),
    (date'2023-12-09', date'2024-02-02', 'A'),
    (date'2024-12-01', date'2025-01-05', 'A'),
    (date'2023-02-01', date'2023-03-07', 'B'),
    (date'2023-06-08', date'2023-07-18', 'B'),
    (date'2024-12-09', date'2024-02-02', 'B');
    
    with a as (
      select a.*,
      case when age(lead(start_dt) over(partition by id order by start_dt), end_dt)
      < interval'9 months' then 1 else 0 end monotony_f
      from test a
      order by id, start_dt
    ),
    b as (
      select start_dt, end_dt, id, coalesce(lag(monotony_f) over(partition by id order by start_dt), 1) monotony_f
      from a
      order by id, start_dt
    )
    select start_dt, end_dt, id from b
    where monotony_f = 0
    union
    select min(start_dt) start_dt, max(end_dt) end_dt, id from b
    where monotony_f = 1
    group by id
    order by id, start_dt
```

But may be there is more correct and natural way? my solution does not cover such example:

| start_dt | end_dt | ID | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-03-08 | A | i |
| 2023-05-08 | 2023-06-18 | A | i+1 |
| 2023-12-09 | 2024-02-02 | A | i+2 |
| 2024-12-01 | 2025-01-05 | A | i+3 |
| 2025-11-01 | 2025-12-07 | A | i+4 |
| 2026-01-08 | 2026-07-18 | A | i+5 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example

```
with a as (
  select a.*
    ,case when age(start_dt,lag(end_dt,1,start_dt)over(partition by id order by start_dt))
            < interval'9 months' 
     then 0 
     else 1 -- start new group
     end monotony_f
  from test a
  order by id, start_dt
),
b as (
  select a.*
      -- group number
     ,sum(monotony_f)over(partition by id order by start_dt) monotony_grn
  from a
)
-- collapse group to one row
select min(start_dt) start_dt,max(end_dt) end_dt,id
from b
group by id,monotony_grn
order by id,min(start_dt);
```

before grouping

| start_dt | end_dt | id | age | monotony_f | monotony_grn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-03-08 | A | 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-05-08 | 2023-06-18 | A | 2 mons | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-12-09 | 2024-02-02 | A | 5 mons 21 days | 0 | 0 |
| 2024-12-01 | 2025-01-05 | A | 9 mons 28 days | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 | 2023-03-07 | B | 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-06-08 | 2023-07-18 | B | 3 mons 1 day | 0 | 0 |
| 2024-12-09 | 2024-02-02 | B | 1 year 4 mons 22 days | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-03-08 | C | 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-05-08 | 2023-06-18 | C | 2 mons | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-12-09 | 2024-02-02 | C | 5 mons 21 days | 0 | 0 |
| 2024-12-01 | 2025-01-05 | C | 9 mons 28 days | 1 | 1 |
| 2025-11-01 | 2025-12-07 | C | 9 mons 27 days | 1 | 2 |
| 2026-01-08 | 2026-07-18 | C | 1 mon 1 day | 0 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

```
with recursive x as (
select
    sk,
    id,
    start_dt ,
    end_dt,
    sk || '' sk_path
from
    test
    --where sk=1
union all
select
    t2.sk sk,
    t2.id,
    x.start_dt ,
    t2.end_dt,
    x.sk_path || t2.sk
from
    test t2
join x on
    x.id = t2.id
    and x.sk + 1 = t2.sk
    and age(t2.start_dt ,
    x.end_dt) < interval '9 months' 

          )
select
    sk,
    id,
    start_dt ,
    end_dt,
    sk_path
from
    x
where
    not exists (
    select
        1
    from
        x x2
    where
        x.id = x2.id
        and (( x.start_dt > x2.start_dt
            and x.start_dt < x2.end_dt )
        or 
( x.end_dt > x2.start_dt
            and x.end_dt < x2.end_dt ) ))
```

Comment: When you just include code it will loose the formatting when posted. To keep the format highlight the  it then click the {} above the input box.  Further code only answers are often not useful. Adding description of what the code does or why particular method chosen greatly helps. But nice job, keep answering.

Comment: I used recursive or hierarchial query approch above. I added sk identity column to hold row .